# make a matrix from a list of dictionaries in python3

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix

I have a list of dictionaries like this example:

example:

```
a = [{'C': 3742, 'A': 38799, 'F': 66, 'D': 848, 'B': 12953, 'E': 140}, {'C': 2319, 'A': 23551, 'F': 33, 'D': 568, 'B': 8192, 'E': 87}]
```

for every single dictionary in the list I would like to sort the items based on the the Keys from A to F. and then make a list of lists (of the sorted dictionary) but only from the values of dictionary. here is the expected output:

expected output:

```
res = [[38799, 12953, 3742, 848, 140, 66], [23551, 8192, 2319, 568, 87, 33]]
```

to do so I made the following code in python:

```
res = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    for e in sorted(a[i].keys()):
        res.append(a[i][e])
```

but it does not return what I want. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Well what does it return?

Answer (score 3):

You want to put the result of from the dictionaries to an array, before adding to the final results

```
a = [{'C': 3742, 'A': 38799, 'F': 66, 'D': 848, 'B': 12953, 'E': 140}, {'C': 2319, 'A': 23551, 'F': 33, 'D': 568, 'B': 8192, 'E': 87}]
res = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    sub_res = []
    for e in sorted(a[i].keys()):
        sub_res.append(a[i][e])
    res.append(sub_res)
```

A shorter version of this would be:

```
res = [ [i[e] for e in sorted(i.keys())] for i in a ]
```

Comment: There's no reason to call `dict.keys()`. You can just pass `sorted(i)`.

Comment: I don't see the problem with making it more explicit, especially for people who are new to Python

Answer (score 1):

To sort items you can use built-in function [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values):

```
a = [{'C': 3742, 'A': 38799, 'F': 66, 'D': 848, 'B': 12953, 'E': 140}, {'C': 2319, 'A': 23551, 'F': 33, 'D': 568, 'B': 8192, 'E': 87}]
b = [[i[k] for k in sorted(i)] for i in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use List comprehension. Avoid using loops.

```
 y = [[i[key]for key in sorted(i.keys())] for i in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a list instead of adding individual elements in **res** list.

```
res = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    temp = []
    for e in sorted(a[i].keys()):
        temp.append(a[i][e])
    res.append(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method using the function `items` of dict:

```
>>> [[i[1] for i in sorted(e.items())] for e in a]
[[38799, 12953, 3742, 848, 140, 66], [23551, 8192, 2319, 568, 87, 33]]
>>>
```

It sorts the values by keys.